# Error while installing drivers

Tags: 12.04

When I tried to install additional drivers in Ubuntu 12.02 via terminal,I got this error message:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
[sudo] password for reidsr: 
Error: need a repository as argument

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
                      Reidar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is to run all commands together *(Like a single command*).
Please try to run first...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then hit Enter to add the repository, and finally run the...

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install *Pkg to install*
```

The `&&` will execute commands in series, and only if the first things return success.

Kind Regards.